# Insert data in two table at the same time in creating an API

Tags: database, laravel, api

This is my first time creating an API. I want to insert data in two table at the same time.

I have a Listing table and Category table. Relationships of the table is ***one List => has many Category***

***Listing columns***

- id
- title
- description

***Category columns***

- id
- listing_id
- category_name

This is my code so far in my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return Listings::create($request->all());
    }
```

***Listing Model***

```
 protected $table = 'testing_table';

    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'listing_id', 'id');
    }
```

***Category Model***

```
 protected $table = 'sample_category';
```

***Routes***

```
Route::post('listings', 'ListingsController@store');
```

***Note:*** Listing and category will be saved together.

Comment: So your request will have category_name(s) as well?

Comment: @user3532758 yes it is. hmm is that possible? or is there other way to do the inserting of two table?

Comment: yeah, check the answer that was posted just now. But, that one gives you a proper example of saving one. So you deduce `saving many` based on all category names you send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to make sure each model has the `$fillables` property set to avoid mass assignment issues. Second, you have to send the category name along with the request.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // You might want to do some validations

    $listing = Listings::create($request->all());

    $category = $listing->categories()->create([
        'category_name' => $request->input('category_name')
    ]);

    // And you can return the date however you see fit.
    return response()->json([
        'listing' => $listing,
        'category' => $category
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But only 1 category is inserted in my category table. Or is there a proper way to test it in postman?

Comment: Would you like to create more than one category? if so then you have to use a different endpoint for that then associate it with the new `listing` when it's been created or create a new one if none exists. But to test the answer I just gave with postman you can make a post request to this endpoint with the following form data `title`, `description`, and `category_name`.

Comment: Okay got your point. Your code works fine with me. Thank you so much. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  try {
        $input = $request->all();
        \DB::beginTransaction();
         $id = Listing::create($input)->id;
         $cat = Category::create([
             'listing_id' => $id,
             'category_name' => $input['category_name'],
            ]);
        \DB::commit();
         return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'code'=> '200', 'data' => 'as per your requirment'], 200);
   } catch (\Throwable $th) {
     \DB::rollBack();
     echo "<pre>";print_r($th->__toString());die;
   }
}
```

to insert more rows then we have to check another way. Please provide your request data.
Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your codes gives me another idea on how to do it. This helps  also. ^_^